# How to match hypothesis with references using BLEU?

Tags: python, bleu

In the following `sys` contains `happy` that is the exact match for the second reference, but why the bleu score is still zero?

```
import sacrebleu
sys = ["happy"] 
refs = [["like achieve"], 
        ["happy"]] 

b3 = sacrebleu.corpus_bleu(sys, refs)
print("b3", b3.score)
print("b3", round(b3.score,2))
```

It prints

```
b3 0.0
b3 0.0
```

If BLEU isn't a good metric for this purpose, I look for a metric that can score the match or substrings in the hypothesis with any reference. I thought the BLEU score is for the same purpose!

Answer (score 1):

BLEU is defined as a geometrical average of (modified) n-gram precisions for unigrams up to 4-grams (times brevity penalty). Thus if there is no matching 4-gram (no 4-tuple of words) in the whole test set, BLEU is 0 by definition. BLEU was designed for scoring test sets with hundreds of sentences where such case is very unlikely. For scoring single sentences, you can use a sentence-level version of BLEU which uses some kind of smoothing, but the results are still not ideal. You can also use a character-based metric, e.g. chrF (`sacrebleu -m chrf`).

You can also pass `use_effective_order=True` to corpus_bleu so that only the matched n-gram orders are counted instead of 4 n-grams. However, in that case, the metric is not exactly what people would refer to BLEU.